# Ruby/Rails - Is there a workaround for this double render error ( Render + Redirect )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue where I think I need to use both a redirect and a render within the same action and I keep getting the double render error so I wondered if anyone could see another way.

I have a form with a select box and a button that allows users to choose from a set of cities to navigate to.

```
<%= form_tag root_path, :method => :post do %>
  <%= select_tag :city, options_for_select(%w{ Pittsburgh Philadelphia Austin }) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Change City" %>
<% end %>
```

and in the controller, I check for the city parameters then redirect to the desired page.

```
def index
  if params[:city] == "Pittsburgh"
    redirect_to pittsburgh_path
  elsif params[:city] == "Philadelphia"
    redirect_to philadelphia_path
  elsif params[:city] == "Austin"
    redirect_to austin_path         
  end
  render :layout => false
end
```

But on this page I've created a specific layout/design which is only on that page so I just turned off the application layout.

Can I perform the navigation actions and turn off the rendering of the application layout at the same time?

Comment: The issue is that `redirect_to` et al. do not return from the action, so you just have to make sure that your offending `render` is not reached.  At the very simplest you could just put the `render` into an `else` block of your conditional, so it only happens if no redirects occur.

Comment: You could/should define those cities in one place and use it both for display and for the business logic. After verifying that `params[:city]` is in the list, you can do `send :"#{params[:city].downcase}_path"` in your controller to call the relevant route helper.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, move the checks in a `before_filter`.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :redirect_customized_cities, :only => :index

  def index
    render :layout => false
  end

  protected

    def redirect_customized_cities
      case params[:city]
        when "Pittsburgh"
          redirect_to pittsburgh_path
        when "Philadelphia"
          redirect_to philadelphia_path
        when "Austin"
          redirect_to austin_path
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do a return statement after any redirect; like returning true or false after the redirect will halt the method chain.